# How can I turn my python script into a web app? I have a scraper that takes an input and displays an output, so I'd like that to be the web app

Tags: python, web-applications

essentially i have a python script that takes an input from the user, and scrapes the relevant data and outputs it. I thought it'd be neat to turn this into a web app, where should i start?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some frameworks such as Flask or Django.
I wrote a small program which automates the process for simple scripts.
https://github.com/bkb3/py2webapp